# Trouble with ttk.Entry.selection_present() and ttk.Entry.selection_clear() in tkinter 8.5 and python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.3

I need `entry` to contain only one file selection at a time. As it stands now, if the user hits `button` multiple times to select multiple files (say they selected the wrong file at first or they changed their mind), `entry` concatenates these multiple filenames all together. Basically, I want `entry` to contain only the user's last file selection.

**Example Code:**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog

def browse():
    if entry.selection_present() == 1:
        entry.selection_clear()
    entry.insert(0, filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=frame))

root = Tk()

frame = ttk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()
entry = ttk.Entry(frame, width=100)
entry.pack()
button = ttk.Button(frame, text="Browse", command=browse)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Neither `entry.selection_present()` nor `entry.selection_clear()` do what I expect. `entry.selection_present()` always outputs 0, and `entry.selection_clear()` seems to do nothing.

I was able to get my code to work if I changed the `if` block to:

```
if entry.get() != "":
    entry.delete(0,1000)
```

but this seems kind of hackish because the arguments - delete all characters up to 1000 - is arbitrary. What I really want is to clear the entire previous file selection.

Tkinter 8.5 documentation:  https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/ttk_entry.htm#M23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `END` (or 'end') to denote the end of the entry.

```
entry.delete(0, END)
```

Above statement will delete entry content. (from begining(0) to the end).

---

Alternatively, you can bind the entry with StringVar object, and later call `set('')` to clear the content.

```
v = StringVar()
entry = Entry(master, textvariable=v)

# to clear
v.set('')
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response! So are `entry.selection_present()` and `entry.selection_clear()` unusable?

Comment: @BigSharpie, selection in entry means ... selected region (selected by mouse drag, Shift + arrow, or ....)